# How to FilterItems by Contains

Tags: c#, podio

I can collect items if I have the exact string of a text field but I need to collect items if I have a partial string in a text field.

Here is the code that I have for exact match...

```
public static async Task<int> Items_With_String(int appId, string textFieldId, string stringToSearch)
{

    var filter = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {textFieldId, stringToSearch }
    };

    var filteredItems = await Program.podio.ItemService.FilterItems(appId: appId, filters: filter);

    foreach (var item in filteredItems.Items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{stringToSearch} found in {item.Title}");
    }

    return filteredItems.Total;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of FilterItems, you can use Search functionality.

you can refer below link for more info.

https://developers.podio.com/doc/search/search-in-app-4234651

please see the sample

```
                bool isContinue = true;
                var limit = 0;
                var offSet = 0;
                while (isContinue)
                {
                    var items = podio.SearchService.SearchInApp(appId, stringToSearch, limit, offset);
                    offSet = offSet + limit;
                    limit = limit + 100;
                    isContinue = // check if you have value;
                }
```

Comment: Thank you for the link. Unfortunately Podio api docs only give examples for PHP and Ruby. I wish there was better info for C#. I use [http://podio.github.io/podio-dotnet/](http://podio.github.io/podio-dotnet/) a lot but it doesn't include search functions from what I've read. Can you please provide an sample?

Comment: @Xiolin if the partial search API method is not available in the nuget then maybe you can try applying the search on top of what you receive from the same api. it's not as efficient but does the job.

Comment: I can help you with a sample, i will update my answer with sample code soon, may be in 3 hr

Comment: I have updated a sample code, not checked the functionality. Hope it helps

Comment: Tested it out. SearchService searches everything. A global search. It doesn't return which field it found the string in but if the string is unique enough it would do the trick. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked. I think you can specify the field name in the app when you do the search. i will check and update the answer

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually provided the implementation of `FilterItems` method.

But generally for a partial match you may use `linq` query and add a `where`
clause with a predicate to do the partial match. Here i give you a sample of
how it looks like so you could use it for your list and filter properties.

```
string filter = "something";
List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>();
// add items to the list
myList.Where(item => item.Contains(filter));
// or for the partial match with a shared beginning
myList.Where(item => item.StartsWith(filter));
```

Hope this would be helpful to your case.

Comment: FilterItems  is a method from a nuget package, which makes some api calls

Comment: @AkbarBadhusha well i'm not sure what type is your filter, but probably you could pass some sort of predicate to it. something similar to the manual way i posted. maybe not exactly a linq predicate but maybe a made up condition class.

Comment: FilterItems method is used to get items from PODIO with specific values in it. For partial search there is another API Call called search. I have added it as an answer above. Just wanted to let you know FilterItems wasn't implemented by the person who asked this question. Its a method in the Podio library nuget package.

Comment: Thank you Akbar for clarifying. I tagged Podio but I should have mentioned it in the question.